# RegEx validation Issue for allowing multiple whitespaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a requirement to do a field validation using regEx. The requirement is not to have any special characters. It is working for me for a single white space, but not for multiple white spaces. It does not work if there is a white space at the beginning. Can you please help me with this?

This is what I used:

```
^(\w+ ?)*$
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for

```
^[\w ]*$
```

The `^` and `$` are anchors for the start/end of the string, the `[...]` is called a character class and would allow only `[A-Za-z0-9_ ]`. The `*` is a quantifier and means zero or more times, thus the expression would also allow an empty string. If this is not what you want, change it to `+` instead of the `*`. Please note that this would also allow a string with only spaces (it really depends on what you want).